# figure out how I got a Java package

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I am running somebody else's program on my computer, and they have imports like:

```
import weka.classifiers.CostMatrix;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier;
import weka.core.*;
```

The program actually works for me, but I am surprised because **weka** is a pretty specialized program, so I doubt it is distributed with Java. I never installed weka using any package manager, and I have searched the program code and it doesn't contain any weka packages explicitly.

Do you have any tips for figuring out 1) where these packages are installed, and 2) how I "got" these packages on my local computer? I have read that Java doesn't have a centralized package manager like Python or Perl do, so that might make it harder. I am super new to Java so any basic tips about package management would also be appreciated.

Comment: Check your classpath.  How are you running it? Are you using Maven?

Comment: `echo %CLASSPATH%` just gives me back `%CLASSPATH%` so I guess it's not set? I am running it through IntelliJ IDEA, but it's using the Java SDK and I know where that is. As for Maven, I don't know how to figure out if this program is using that. How do I do that?

Comment: In IntelliJ, press `F4` to open the module settings, where you can see all the dependencies and their location for each of the modules.

Comment: @xiaofeng.li F4 doesn't work (I have the default key mappings). Do you know how to get there through the menus?

Comment: Right click on the project and there should be an "Open Module Settings" in the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages are *dependencies* of your project, so they have probably been downloaded automatically by a tool that manages dependencies.

There are several possible *build tools* that can do that. Since you are working with Java/JVM, the usual suspects are [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or maybe (less likely) [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/).

In your case, the most probable scenario is:

1. **A Maven plugin** somewhere in your IDE manages the dependencies and downloads the jars (`mvn` in console less likely: you would have noticed if you used it)
2. **A `pom.xml`** build definition file lists all the dependencies
3. **A weka dependency** is probably declared somewhere in the pom, it should look roughly like this:

-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
    <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

4. **The JARs** are stored in a hidden directory `.m2` (or maybe `.ivy`) in your home directory.

The idea is that you can simply get the source code files and the `pom.xml`, and let `Maven` (or a similar build tool) download all dependencies, get all the required compiler plugins (or test-coverage tools, or whatever), and build your project. If you tried to do without a build tool, you would have to pass around eternally long lists of dependencies with version numbers that have to be obtained somehow before your program can be compiled, and this would be just a huge mess.

---

**Edit**: It is probably downloaded from here: [Maven Central: weka-stable](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.8.0)

Comment: Bingo, there is a pom.xml in my root folder. It contains the following:
<dependency>
            <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
            <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: It also separately has URL paths to repositories under <pluginRepositories>, though I'm not sure how the two connect to each other. But I'm guessing the packages are getting pulled from there.

Comment: @Stephen The weka itself is probably pulled directly from Maven Central (see update of my post). The plugins are slightly different, this is for downloading the plugins that are used by maven itself, they are not used by your code or weka.

Comment: Thanks. How do I know if Maven is using Maven Central? Or is that built-in?

Comment: @Stephen It's kind-of built-in: the maven central repository is by default it in the so-called "Super pom" that is installed together with maven. But it's essentially just another xml file with a bunch of default settings in the same format as the pom.xml that you've already seen. More on this: [The pom and the super pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't run unless those packages are on the classpath and passed at runtime via

```
java -classpath
```

Or you're running an uber JAR file that does contain the libraries.

Common solutions for dependency management include a `pom.xml` (Maven), `build.gradle` (Gradle), or `build.sbt` (SBT).

While those aren't the only options, another solution would be those JAR libraries have been copied into your Java installation somehow

Comment: Never really used Ant, but... did Ant somehow lost too much market share in the past few years? It's nice to see SBT in your list of usual suspects for a Java project though :] However, I strongly suspect that if they use weka, they probably don't use SBT. If they were already using SBT, they would probably also be comfortable enough with scala to do their machine learning stuff on Spark ML ;)

Comment: Ant itself isn't dependency management, AFAIK. Adding Ivy controls that functionality, and I've only seen one company using Ant so far for managing some monolith Tomcat app. Project dependency inheritance and Docker integrations has driven the other projects

Comment: Thanks for sharing some information about the surrounding landscape :]